# How to show the API image using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swifty-json, collectionview

I would like to know how to show the API image from API to UIImage. I can get the result from console and I can't show the images from internet to collection view.

```
public var foodImage = [String]()
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainPageCollectionViewCell
    //Below is fine and it can display food title from Internet
    cell.FoodTitle.text = self.foodTitle[indexPath.item]
    //Cannot display API image from Internet
    cell.Food.image = foodImage[indexPath.item] as? UIImage

    return cell
}
```

Here is the code of retrieve API result:

```
self.foodImage = json["hits"].arrayValue.map {$0["recipe"]["image"].stringValue}
print(self.foodImage)
```

Comment: I think you get the link of the image from your API. Use [Kingfisher] https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher for image caching.

Answer (score 2):

There is one cocoa pod available for load image from URL
[click here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SDWebImage)

Add this in your pod file

```
pod 'SDWebImage'
```

```
import SDWebImage

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: yourURLString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Comment: I have a one array to store the image URLs and I would like to display it using Collection View. Is it possible to use SDWebImage?

Comment: yes @lpy , SDWebImage is only for downloading and displaying the image from the URL.

Comment: I don't know the syntax about using the array in the SSWebImage. Could you mind to give me an example?

Comment: if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollVCell", for: indexPath) as? ImageCollVCell {
            cell.imgaeView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: arr[indexPath.row])
            return cell
        }

Comment: I added cell.Food.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: foodImage[indexPath.row])), but there is error occurred. (Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range). Is there any idea about that? thanks a lot.